# ADF expression to convert array to comma separated string

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

This appears to be pretty basic but I am unable to find a suitable pipeline expression function to achieve this.

I have set an array variable VAR1 with the following value, which is an output from a SQL Lookup activity in an ADF pipeline:

```
[
    {
        "Code1": "1312312"
    },
    {
        "Code1": "3524355"
    }
]
```

Now, I need to convert this into a comma separated string so I can pass it to a SQL query in the next activity - something like:

`"'1312312','3524355'"`

I am unable to find an expression function to iterate over the array elements, nor convert an array to a string. The only pipeline expression functions I see are to convert string to array and not the other way around.

Am I missing something basic? How can this be achieved?

Comment: Azure Data Factory now includes a function called `join` that you can use to do this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using a ForEach loop activity to iterate over my array and use a Set Variable task with a concat expression function to create my comma separated string.

Wish they had an iterator function in the expression language itself, that would have made it much easier.

Comment: I'm accepting my answer as have not found another solution for this yet. Looks like ADF is probably not the right place for this type of computation, these probably should be done in a custom script task, or source/sink side.
It doesn't make sense to pay for several activities just to perform a string concatenation!

Comment: @coder_andy, Thanks for the answer. Can you please share how you did this? "Set Variable task with a concat expression function to create my comma separated string"

Answer (score 11):

Use 'join' function present in 'collection' functions in 'Add dynamic content'. For example:

```
join(variables('ARRAY_VARIABLE'), ',')
```

Comment: How Can i convert this ["10","12","23"] in this 10,12,23 ?

Answer (score 6):

I had this same issue and was not totally satisfied just using the join function because it keeps the keys from the json object. Also, using an iterator approach can work but is needlessly expensive and slow if you have a long list. Here was my approach, using join and replace:

```
replace(replace(join(variables('VAR1'), ','), '{"Code1":', ''), '}', ''))
```

This will give you exactly the output you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

In case, you just have two elements in the array, then you can do something like:

```
@concat(variables('variable_name')[0].Code1, ',', variables('variable_name')[1].Code1)
```

Comment: The 2 elements was just an example. I can have any number of elements in the array, as it is returned from a sql select.

Comment: ok short question, are you using data flow by any change for this SQL select?

Comment: No, Sql select is in a lookup task.